# Symfony2 - AuthenticationSuccessHandler redirect to original request

Tags: authentication, redirect, symfony

I've overridden [`AuthenticationSuccessHandler`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.2/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler.php) but I'd like to keep the referer redirection behavior on success.

I saw that the default handler [uses `$request->headers->get('Referer')`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.2/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler.php#L104), I tried to do the same on my custom handler:

```
if (($targetUrl = $request->headers->get('Referer'))
        && $targetUrl !== $this->options['login_path']) {
    die($targetUrl);
```

Returns me the login path:

> `http://my_host/login`

instead of the original request. I think that it's because the firewall has previously redirected the user to the login page.

The default handler redirects me fine, so I'm wondering why mine does not.

How can I get the original request from my custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look [here](https://github.com/symfony/Security/blob/master/Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler.php). `determineTargetUrl` is what you're asking for.

Added: It saves return path in session and then restores it (line 98). If there is no return path in user's session, handler takes Referer.

Comment: That's the link I've put twice in my question but the problem is that `$request->headers->get('Referer')` is always returning `/login`

Comment: as you've also noticed `because the firewall has previously redirected the user to the login page` So request is done from /login page, that apears as Referer in your handler

Comment: So the first question was: How does the default handler manage it ?

Comment: It saves return path in session and then restores it (line 98). If there is no return path in user's session, handler takes Referer.

Comment: Ok I didn't even see the `getSession` before, it works fine, thanks. You should put it on your answser.